# Parent window freezes when window.open which triggers print onLoad

Tags: javascript, html, printing, window

I have a scenario where in my webpage i do a window.open() which opens up another window whose `onLoad()` invokes `window.print()`. In this flow, the parent `window` remains frozen disallowing any links to be clicked on. How to I get away with this problem?

For example:

An HTML page has three links: create, manage and print. The javascript code for the print link is the following:

```
    var url = '/actions/print/';
    var win = window.open(url,"Title_","resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,directories=no,titlebar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,width="+width+",height="+height);
```

now, the HTML rendered by `/actions/print` is:

```
<html><body onload="window.print();"> ... Content goes here ...</body></html>
```

So as you can see, clicking on print opens up a new window and triggers print immediately. In this state, when i go back to parent window with three links and try to click on other links, it doesn't work and appears frozen.

Comment: You can try using a timeout? `window.setTimeout(function(){window.print();},0);` Tell me if it works :)

Comment: @Sripaul So, did my answer help you in any way?

Comment: @www139, it didn't works; https://jsfiddle.net/stanimirsp5/a761hu2s/2/

Answer (score 18):

You can't resolve this issue on OS X. Which I am pretty sure you only tested on.

Here is how I came to that conclusion after testing on different browsers and plateforms.

- Chrome, Safari and Firefox on OS X did not allow interactivity with parent window when a **print modal** was opened from a child window (closing the print dialog, but not the pop up, re-enabled interactivity).
- IE8 on Win XP, IE11, Chrome and Firefox (all on Win7) always allowed interactivity with this same scenario.

This led me to believe this was an OS X restriction or recommendation. On further research, here is what I found on developer.apple.com, confirming my doubts:

***A document-modal dialog prevents the user from doing anything else within a particular document***. The user can switch to other documents in the app and to other apps. **Document-modal dialogs should be sheets**, which are described in Using Document-Modal Dialogs (Sheets).

*Use a sheet when multiple documents can appear in a single window at different times. For example, **a tabbed browser can display different documents in a single window at different times. A sheet is appropriate in this situation**, even though it applies to only the document that is currently visible in the window. Because **users must in effect dismiss the current document before viewing a different document in the same window, they should first dismiss the sheet**.*

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/OSXHIGuidelines/WindowDialogs.html